# How to format fraction output in terminal with printf

Tags: c, terminal, format, output, printf

This may be really dumb but I have been unable to print a fraction to my terminal. How do I make my fraction look like this [image: fraction two thirds] and not(2/3).

I've tried the code below but I don't know how I'll print multiple fractions on the same line.

```
printf("2\n");
printf("-\n");
printf("3\n");
```

Comment: make a 2D array of characters that will represent the output on the screen, format your output in there (which is easier as you can access any cell in any order), then print the array out.

Comment: What you have shown is also not a fraction on a single line.  It is a fraction depicted on 3 separate lines.  Is this depiction acceptable to as long as you can show multiple fractions in the same manner on the same 3 lines?

Comment: Yes, it's fine with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly, but if the example of one fraction on 3 lines, as you have shown in your post is okay, then this illustrates multiple fractions on the same 3 lines.  Note the use of width specifier in format strings:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char array[3][5] = {{'1','2','3','4','5' },
                              {'-','-','-','-','-'},
                              {'2','3','4','5','6' }};
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("%6c", array[i][j]);
            //       | width specifier, change value as needed for formatting.
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
[image]

For a prettier output, you could always use [unicode characters](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/decomposition/%3Cfraction%3E), but then you would need to use [wchar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/extensible-storage-engine/wchar), and still be limited to seeing Vulgar fraction form:  `1/2`.

Answer (score 1):

In ASCII text mode, you can only print fractions on a single line if these fractions are hardcoded characters in the character set that you are using.

The lower 128 characters of the ASCII character set do not contain any such characters. Depending on the character set you are using, the upper 128 may contain a few such characters, such as `¼`, `½` and `¾`. But it is unlikely that you will find all characters that you need.

Unicode will probably support more such characters, but since you are probably looking for a more general and flexible solution, you will not be able to use a text terminal, but will have to make a graphical application which uses a [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) renderer or something similar.